# GoCD : Get the material name that triggered pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, go-cd

In my GoCD, I have a deploy pipeline that deploys the artifact to an environment. Let's call it `DP`. Now, I have various build pipelines for building the artifacts, let's call these `B1.. Bn`. Following is the GoCD structure :

`DP <- B1.. Bn` (i.e. Deployment gets triggered by any of the builds after successful completion)

I am using GoCD's [Properties API](https://api.gocd.org/current/#properties) to export/fetch the properties. Properties are exported by build pipelines and fetched by deploy pipeline (as explained [here](https://support.thoughtworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/213254026-Pass-variables-to-other-pipelines)). Now, to get a property name in deploy pipeline, I need to get the name of the material, e.g.:

```
curl 'http://ci.example.com/go/properties/PipelineName/541/StageName/1/JobName/cruise_agent' \
      -u 'username:password'
```

However, in the deploy pipeline, I don't have the name of the parent pipeline, i.e. the one that caused deploy to execute. Do we know how to get the name of the material that caused the pipeline to execute?